# tortoisesvn - Error REPORT of ../../../!svn/vcc/default: could not read chunk delimiter

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to update my project and it update all of my project files and download lots of project's file (271 MB) [Although I regularly update my project], After download 271 MB, it has just stopped to download project and the following message is appearing ::

```
Error  REPORT of '/[path_to_repo]/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read chunk delimiter:
Error  connection timeout (https://www.myprojectlink)
Completed!
```